# How to block ALL countries except Europe, USA, Canada and the former USSR?

Tags: firewall, cloudflare

How to block ALL countries in a cloudflare, except for Europe, the USA, Canada and the former USSR?

It is long and unreliable to list all the countries, I might miss something. Regional affiliation:

`(not ip.geoip.continent in {"EU" "NA" "AS"})`

includes both the countries of the former USSR and Asia (China, Mongolia, etc).

You can or can apply these codes https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#search/code/ in cloudflare?

Comment: Also `NA` is wrong, because it includes also for instance Mexico and Panama and the carribean states like Cuba.

Answer (score 1):

Cloudflare can include the country code of the visitor's IP (in [ISO 3166-1 alpha-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2))

> [Configuring Cloudflare IP Geolocation – Cloudflare Help Center](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168236-What-does-Cloudflare-IP-Geolocation-do-)